# Apple notification message

Tags: notification, iphone, charging

When I connect my iPhone to the charger (on an offline machine A), my Ubuntu online machine B displays this notification:

[image]

How does this happen? I think there is no Apple component installed on the Ubuntu machine. *Settings* -> *Notifications* contains no mention of Apple.

Comment: Did you connect your phone to the PC using a USB port?

Comment: Which version of ubuntu and which iphone?

Comment: iphone 12 connect via USB port. Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: The phone's USB connection reports a manufacturer ID to the PC.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - The message appears on a different machine

Comment: Your question appeared to be about how an Apple device was recognized. Please edit your question to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Apple iTunes downloaded and installed on your Machine B, and the phone is set up for sync functions, like uploading pictures to your online account, the phone itself may be relaying its status to iTunes and that is why you get the warning.

You mentioned that Machine A is "offline" so I assume that means not plugged into any network or internet service. So it should not be producing the message.

I think you may be able to see if it is the iphone broadcasting something or if the iTunes is registering the UDB connection. Try setting your iPhone into Airplane mode, then connect to the USB on Machine A. You can then see if Machine B detected that connection or it was ignored because the phone itself was "offline".

Otherwise, I'd suggest placing the question on Apple's Community Board.

Comment: How do I find the iTunes installation if exists? Settings -> Notifications contains no mention of Apple.